# Examples of non-isomorphic fields with isomorphic group of units and additive group structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, examples-counterexamples

YACP mentions in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623636/is-a-field-determined-by-its-family-of-general-linear-groups#comment1314343_623636) that:

> There are examples of non-isomorphic fields $K$ and $L$ with $(K,+)\cong
>  (L,+)$ and $(K^{\times} ,\cdot)\cong (L^{\times},\cdot)$

Can someone provide an example?

I have found the following [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35358/does-a-finite-rings-additive-structure-and-the-structure-of-its-group-of-units). But there, the underlying structure is a ring. <del>Hence, an answer to the current question is automatically an answer to the old question as well.</del> EDIT: Sorry, the other question asks for **finite** commutative ring, and this won't be possible in the case of fields…

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: @Sanchez This can be a good example as one knows that $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ and $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ are the rings of algebraic integers of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ and $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3)$, respectively and both are euclidean. But their groups of units are not so easy to handle. (Anyway, they are both isomorphic to $\{\pm 1\}\times\mathbb Z$ if I'm not wrong.) That's why I've preferred imaginary quadratic number fields.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An example can be the following: $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt 2)$ and $\mathbb Q(i\sqrt 7)$.

It's well known that these fields are not isomorphic: [quadratic fields are isomorphic if and only if they are equal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9188/is-mathbbq-sqrt2-cong-mathbbq-sqrt3).

It is obvious that their additive groups are isomorphic.

With respect to the multiplicative groups, note that both are isomorphic to $\{\pm1\}\times\mathbb Z^{(\mathbb N)}$ (the last denotes a countable direct sum of copies of the group of integers).

Comment: You could elaborate: why 2 and 7? What is wrong with 3 or 5? - (It's because we know the units and have UFDs, but mentioning that might be fine)